# Unable to connect to CIFS host - Printer setting problem

Tags: 14.04

My printer is HP laser jet pro p1102. It is a share printer.
When I try to print this error message pops up

```
Unable to connect to CIFS host
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Remove printer added via ---- `System Settings`--- `Printers`

Open a terminal.  **(Ctrl+Alt+T)**.

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# apt-get update
# apt-get install --reinstall cups cups-browsed cups-bsd cups-client printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-hpijs hplip sane-utils xsane libcups2  cups-client python3-dbus python3-notify2 python3-imaging python3-pyqt4 gtk2-engines-pixbuf  python3-lxml libsane 
# usermod -a -G lp $USER
# hp-setup
```

Select the printer connection type.

Select the Printer to be Configured, setup tool will display printers detected.

Select the PPD file or driver to be Used for Your Printer, usually you will want to select the recommended.

## [Source](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/about.html)

Comment: I have done all things through # hp-setup. But at this option actually I don't know how to detect my share printer? I have just one printer, at my office. Through windows I detect our share printer through run command and IP address is\\192.168.8.5. At this IP address I can connect my printer. But in ubuntu how I can done this process?

Comment: Try log in on the CUPS web interface and choose to add a new printer. As a device choose "Windows Printer via SAMBA".

Comment: I have done it. But when I tried to **print test page** it says printer error. Then I check it status it says _Processing - Unable to connect to CIFS host, will retry in 60 seconds..._ But nothing happen.

Comment: I tried to **Browse Network** for know my share is working fine. But when I tried to open it says _Unnable to access connection - Failed to retrieve share list from server: Connection timed out_

Comment: After getting some update, my network share folder is opening. But can't print anything as printer error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone having the same issue:

I had the same error message when trying to access the printer with its IP-Address. When I used the hostname, it worked.

--->

This did not work:

```
smb://192.168.0.77/Printer-Name
```

Then I found out the Hostname with `nslookup`:

```
$ nslookup 192.168.0.77
[...] name=printerhost.local
```

This worked:

```
smb://printerhost.local/Printer-Name
```